# ViewModel is recreated when coming back from navigation in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm refactoring original project xml -> compose, and got some issues.
When I navigate `A -> B and Back to A`, the A's viewmodel is recreated.
What I expect is to follow the original lifecycle (onDestroyed, not onDispose).
I already know how to implement lifeCycleObserver in compose, but don't understand the lifeCycle of viewmodel in compose.
I want to use Compose's viewmodel like a fragment's viewmodel for lifecycle, not recreating when recomposed.
Is this thinking anti-pattern in compose? Then, How to remain the viewModel' lifecycle?

I don't want to pass a viewmodel as a parameter Because I have a nested navigation for same compose screen. And don't use same lifecycleOwner(MainActivity's lifeCyclerOwner)

Comment: It might help: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel